# Finding the number of substrings which sum is equal to m

Tags: python

I'm trying some python and I got this:

I have a string S='3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2' and m=9.
I want to know how many substrings with with sum equals m there are.

```
So with S and m above i whould get 7 as a result as:
'3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2'
 _'0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0'_____________
 _'0,4,0,3,1,0,1'_______________
 ___'4,0,3,1,0,1,0'_____________
____'4,0,3,1,0,1'_______________
____________________'0,0,5,0,4'_
______________________'0,5,0,4'_
 _______________________'5,0,4'_
```

Now, the code i came up with does something like that

```
def es1(S,m):
    c = 0
    M = 0
    ls = StringToInt(S)
    for x in ls:
        i= ls.index(x)
        for y in ls[i+1:]:
            M = x + y
            if M == m:
                c += 1
                M = 0
                break
            if M > m:
                M = 0
                break
            else:
                continue
    return c

def StringToInt(ls):
    s = [int(x) for x in ls.split(',')]
    return s
```

Where StringToInt obv gives me a list of int to work with.
The thing I don't get is where my concept is wrong since es1 returns 3

Comment: I don't understand why you're using this loop structure, as it allows the same element to be counted twice.

Comment: It's just the first thing that came to my mind. 
But shouldn't the i+1 solve that problem, it should start every time from the element after x, right?

Comment: If your target number were 6, then this code would find a "solution" on the very first iteration, as both `x` and `y` are 3.  But those are the _same_ element, so it would be incorrect.

Comment: Are all elements in the list assumed to be positive? If they are all positive you could make a faster solution than if negatives are allowed

Comment: yeah, only positives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for man. i felt looking by position was better for this problem so I did it and it worked.

```
def es1(S,m):
    c = 0
    M = 0
    ls = StringToInt(S)

    for i in range(0, len(ls)):
        M = 0
        for x in range(i, len(ls)):
            M += ls[x]
            if M == m:
                c += 1

            elif M >= m:
                break
    return c



def StringToInt(ls):
    s = [int(x) for x in ls.split(',')]
    return s

print(es1("3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2", 9))
```

OUTPUT:

```
7
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use zip to progressively add numbers to a list of sums and count how many 9s you have at each pass:

```
S = '3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2'
m = 9
numbers = list(map(int,S.split(",")))
result  = 0
sums    = numbers
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    result += sums.count(m)
    sums   = [a+b for a,b in zip(sums,numbers[i+1:]) ]
print(result)
```

For a more "functional programming" approach, you can use accumulate from itertools:

```
from itertools import accumulate
numbers = list(map(int,S.split(",")))
ranges  = (numbers[i:] for i in range(len(numbers)))
sums    = (accumulate(r) for r in ranges)
result  = sum( list(s).count(m) for s in sums )
print(result)
```

To explain how this works, let's first look at the content of ranges, which are substrings from each position up to the end of the list:

```
[3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 5, 0, 4, 2]
[5, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 4, 2]
[4, 2]
[2]
```

When we make a cumulative sum of the rows (sums), we obtain the total of values starting at the position defined by the row number and for a length defined by the column number.  e.g. line 5, column 3 represents the sum of 3 values starting at the fifth position:

```
[3, 3, 7, 7, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 18, 18, 22, 24]
[0, 4, 4, 7, 8,  8,  9,  9,  10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 19, 21]
[4, 4, 7, 8, 8,  9,  9,  10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 19, 21]
[0, 3, 4, 4, 5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  11, 11, 15, 17]
[3, 4, 4, 5, 5,  6,  6,  6,  11, 11, 15, 17]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3,  3,  3,  8,  8,  12, 14]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2,  2,  7,  7,  11, 13]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2,  7,  7,  11, 13]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 6,  6,  10, 12]
[1, 1, 1, 6, 6,  10, 12]
[0, 0, 5, 5, 9,  11]
[0, 5, 5, 9, 11]
[5, 5, 9, 11]
[0, 4, 6]
[4, 6]
[2]
```

In this triangular matrix each position corresponds to the sum of one of the possible substrings.  We simply need to count the number of 9s in there to get the result.

The above solutions will perform in O(N^2) time but, if you are concerned with performance, there is a way to obtain the result in O(N) time using a dictionary.  Rather than build the whole sub arrays in the above logic, you could simply count the number of positions that add up to each sum. Then, for the sum at each position, go directly to a previous sum total that is exactly `m` less to get the number of substrings for that position.

```
from itertools import accumulate
from collections import Counter
numbers = map(int,S.split(","))
result  = 0
sums    = Counter([0])
for s in accumulate(numbers):
    result  += sums[s-m]
    sums[s] += 1
print(result)
```

Note that all these solutions support negative numbers in the list as well as a negative or zero target.

Comment: I think it shouldn't be `for i in range(m)` since that looks for sums of sub-lists of length `m`. It is possible for there to be a sub-list of length greater than `m` with a sum of `m` since zeros are allowed in the list. A failing example: `S = '1,0,0,1'`, `m = 2`

Comment: @Oli, You are right it is a range of len(numbers).  That was my mistake.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, your code only looks at sums of pairs of elements from the list. You need to look at sublists.

Here is a `O(n)` complexity solution (i.e. it's efficient since it only scans though the list once):

```
def es2(s, m):
    s = string_to_int(s)
    c = 0
    # index of left of sub-list
    left = 0
    # index of right of sub-list
    right = 0
    # running total of sublist sum
    current_sum = 0
    while True:
        # if the sub-list has the correct sum
        if current_sum == m:
            # add as many zeros on the end as works
            temp_current_sum = current_sum
            for temp_right in range(right, len(s) + 1):
                if temp_current_sum == m:
                    c += 1
                    if temp_right<len(s):
                        temp_current_sum += s[temp_right]
                else:
                    break

        if current_sum >= m:
            # move the left end along and update running total
            current_sum -= s[left]
            left += 1
        else:
            # move the right end along and update running total
            if right == len(s):
                # if the end of the list is reached, exit
                return c

            current_sum += s[right]
            right += 1


def string_to_int(ls):
    s = [int(x) for x in ls.split(',')]
    return s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(es2('3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2', 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code counts how many pairs of numbers there are in the String S which together give m while you actually want to test **all** possible substrings.

You could do something like:

```py
numbers = [3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2]
m = 9

c = 0
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for j in range(len(numbers)-i):
        sum = 0
        for k in numbers[i:i+j]:
            sum += k
        if sum == m:
            c += 1
print(c)
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: It shouldn't return 3 then, since there is no pair equal to 9

Comment: wait, i dont understand, I thought you wanted to find like sets that equal to 9, not just pairs.

Comment: And there is a piar that equals 9, 5+4 is a pair that equals 9

Comment: There are two 4s and one 5 giving three pairs of 4+5

Comment: Yeah i want the sets.

Comment: well with sets, i got thousnads of solutions

Comment: because it counts all posibilities

Comment: Would you give me a hint?

Comment: I added my solution.

Comment: I added mine :)

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

EDIT! ->This Code is actually all possible subsets, not sublists. I am going to leave this here though in case this solution is helpful to anyone who visits this question.

This code gets every solution. If you take a look in the function `es1()` the `result` variable is  huge list of arrays with all the possible solutions.

```
import itertools

def es1(S,m):
    result = [seq for i in range(len(StringToInt(S)), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(StringToInt(S), i) if sum(seq) == m]
    return len(result)

def StringToInt(ls):
    s = [int(x) for x in ls.split(',')]
    return s


print(es1("3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2", 9))
```

OUTPUT:

```
4608
```

There are 4608 possible sets that add to the value 9.

Comment: This does all combinations of subsets, not all sub-lists

Comment: Oh. ok brother let me figure something out.

Comment: Ok man if you take a look at my other answer it works perfectly for what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
s = "3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2"

m = 9

sn = s.replace(",","+") # replace "," with "+"
d = {} # create a dictionary

# create list of strings:
# s2 = ["3+0","0+4","4+0".............]
# s3 = ["3+0+4","0+4+0","4+0+3".............]
# .
# .
# .
for n in range(2,len(s.split(","))):
    d["s%s"%n] = [sn[i:i+(2*n-1)] for i in range(0,len(sn),2)][:-n+1]

# evaluate whether sum of individual lists equal to m or not, then find out how many such lists are there
l = sum([eval(x)==m for y in d.values() for x in y] )
# remember we didnot add s1, i,e check whether individual string == m or not
l = l+sum([x==m for x in s.split(",")])

print(l)

7
```

Comment: Although using `eval` should be safe in this case, it is generally unsafe and not necessary to solve this problem. Using `eval` and manipulating expression strings also leads to messy code. Well commented though!